# not able to manipulate data returned from $.ajax

Tags: dom, jquery

I need to remove an element with the class `.connectNow` from the data returned with the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: pages[i] +'.php',
    data: 'ajax=1',
    success: function(txt) {

        // the following line is not operating as expected
        $(txt).find('.connectNow').remove();
        $('.slide').eq(0).after('<div class="slide">' + txt + '</div>');
        $('.slide').animate({'left':'-=425px'},1500);
    }   
});
```

I've looked at (and tried) the following, none of which seem to help in my situation,  unless I'm implementing them wrong.

- [Can't Manipulate data inserted from an ajax request in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3486385/362769)
- [parse partial html string with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3642203/362769)

Comment: Have you tried assigning `txt` to a temporary variable, and operating on that? Something like `var foo = $(txt); foo.find(...).remove()`?

Comment: txt is not in the DOM when you remove element with .connectNow class. that line is then useless

Comment: @JamWaffles, what difference would that make? In any case, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working version (using fake input xml):

http://jsfiddle.net/jMQX5/1

Some of the seemingly strange choices made are explained with inline comments.

Comment: I don't _see_ any comments... So it seems you're saying the same as @JamWaffles, put the returned `txt` into a variable and then work with it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the data type of your returned ajax to be html (it may be defaulting to text, though jQuery is supposed to guess what it is).

If that doesn't work though here is a little hack which may help you

```
txt = $('<div/>').append(txt).find('.connectNow').remove().end().html();
```